# How do I change an attribute value while switching the order of two elements?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to switch the order of two elements and then change the class name on both of them.

This is the switching part:

```
  <xsl:template match="div[@id='container-4']/div[starts-with(@class,'df-width-40')]">

        <xsl:copy-of select="div[@id='container-5']/div[@class='df-width-100']/div" />

   </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="div[@id='container-5']/div[@class='df-width-100']">

        <xsl:copy-of select="div[@id='container-4']/div[@class='df-width-40']/div" />

    </xsl:template>
```

The code above is supposed to do the following:
Replace the div.df-width-40 in the #container-4 with the div.df-width-100 from #container-5.

Then replace the div.df-width-100 from #container-5 with the div.df-width-40 from #container-4.

Basically just switching the child divs in #container-4 and #container-5.

But I also need to change the class names so the div.df-width-40 changes name to div.df-width-100, and vice verca

Original xml:

```
<div id="container-4">
    <div class="df-width-40">lorem</div>
</div>

<div id="container-5">
    <div class="df-width-100">ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Wanted result after xslt:

```
<div id="container-4">
    <div class="df-width-40">ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container-5">
    <div class="df-width-100">lorem</div>
</div>
```

Caveat:
I can not just get the content of the divs due to complex layout and dynamic content I have no control over. The xpath and element class names have been reduced for clarity.

Comment: Consider to reduce XML input and XSLT code to minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. It is not clear whether the elements you match on with the first two templates are the same whose attribute you want to match. As your first two templates don't use `apply-templates` but instead create a `div` result and copy nodes I don't see why you would expect the other template to be used. If the elements are unrelated then please show the relevant input.

Comment: Hi, @MartinHonnen. I have tried my best to make it a bit clearer what my goal is, and also changed the question a little (from changing class name of one of the divs, to both) Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy the existing div and its attribute(s) and then only swap the contents of the divs, as in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@id='container-4']/div[starts-with(@class,'df-width-40')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, 
            ../following-sibling::div[@id='container-5']/div[@class='df-width-100']/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@id='container-5']/div[@class='df-width-100']">
       <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, 
            ../preceding-sibling::div[@id='container-4']/div[@class='df-width-40']/node()"/>           
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

then you should get the result you want,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
<div id="container-4">
    <div class="df-width-40">lorem</div>
</div>

<div id="container-5">
    <div class="df-width-100">ipsum</div>
</div>
</body>
```

is transformed into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><body>
<div id="container-4">
    <div class="df-width-40">ipsum</div>
</div>

<div id="container-5">
    <div class="df-width-100">lorem</div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRJm